# What should I do if I find a better solution to a question I've already answered?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, multiple-answers

Three months ago, I posted an answer to *[How to unlink my Documents folder from my OneDrive account?](https://superuser.com/q/1205668/358766)*. My answer was upvoted, and is currently marked as [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1206452/358766).

In the past week, I've found [an alternate answer from PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2993360/windows/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-saving-files-to-onedrive.html) which I believe to be a much simpler and more effective solution than what I'd previously posted.

**How should I handle finding a better solution to a question I've already answered?**

Should I edit my existing accepted answer, or should I post it as a separate answer?

Comment: If it's an entirely different solution, you should post a new answer.

Comment: @yannis Should I mention my other answer? Or should I avoid recommending one solution over the other.

Comment: If it's a good solution to the problem, it doesn't really matter. Up to you, really.